# How to append a string and html tag in ternary operator condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a ternary condition in React

```jsx
return <span>
    {
        data.length > 136
            ? this.trimStringLength(data, 136) + (<span>see more...</span>) 
            : data
    }
</span>;
```

Here, `this.trimStringLength` provides a trim string.
The result should be "some data here see more..." but I am geeting "some data here[object Object]"

How can I concatenate to get the required result?

Comment: What do you have in your `data`? And what do you want to print?

Comment: @RyanLe data is string of characters like "some data here". I already mentioned the required result.

Comment: Just remove the inner `span`: `this.trimStringLength(data, 136) + 'see more...'`

Comment: No I want to provide some css to see more text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

E.g.:

```
<span>
  {data.length > 136
    ? <>{this.trimStringLength(data, 136)} <span>see more...</span></>
    : data}
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this, no need to use the `+` sign

```
<span>
{
 data.length > 136
  ? 
   (<>{this.trimStringLength(data, 136)} <span> see more...</span></>)
  : 
   data
}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are concatenating a string and an object instead of two strings.

Have you tried replacing the span element with a string, like so ?

```
<span>
{
 data.length > 136
  ? 
   this.trimStringLength(data, 136) + "see more..." 
  : 
   data
}
</span>
```

Comment: I wanted to provide some CSS to only "see more" text. The solution will join the see more with the string and I wont be able to differentiate them

Comment: You might need to create a `span` that displays `this.trimStringLength(data, 136)` or `data` and to create another `span` that displays `"see more"` or nothing. You could then wrap your 2 spans inside a div and style them separately.

Comment: Thanks I got the similar solution above