# Writing JSX with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const ModalButton = ({ label, mode }) => {
  return (
    <button type="submit">
      {mode == "new" && (
        <FaPlusCircle style={{ fontSize: "20px", paddingTop: "6px" }} />) label
      }
    </button>
  );
};
```

This label is underlined as red in my code editor. Why it won't let me to have JavaScript with JSX?

Comment: This is invalid syntax, what are you trying to do?

Comment: What does `label` contains?

Comment: I'm trying to conditional render an icon if mode is new render this else another one. Label is a prop (string value) I want to have it next to the icon

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69011851/how-to-append-a-string-and-html-tag-in-ternary-operator-condition, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886726/why-do-i-get-the-error-expressions-must-have-one-parent-element-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second operand of `&&` has to be a single value; right now, you're trying to give it two. To treat the icon and the text node after it as a unit (a single value), you need to wrap them in something, such as a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html): `<>_____</>`

```
const ModalButton = ({ label, mode }) => {
    return (
        <button type="submit">
            {mode == "new" && (
                <>
                    <FaPlusCircle style={{ fontSize: "20px", paddingTop: "6px" }} />
                    {label}
                </>
            )}
        </button>
    );
};
```

(You also had the `)` in the wrong place; I've fixed it above. It shouldn't be just after the icon, it should be after the entire operand for `&&` [so with this change, it's after the end of the fragment].)

Also, if you want to use the value of `label`, you'll need to wrap it in a JSX expression (as above): `{label}`.

Comment: This shows me an error to before the label ')' showing in red color

Comment: @MishenThakshana - Ah, you weren't *missing* the `)`, it was just in the wrong place. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @MishenThakshana - Ah yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

As rightly commented by [@Konrad Linkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089567/konrad-linkowski)

> This is invalid syntax

**What is the issue with it?**

What you are using is called expression. So *condition1 && condition2* will return `false` if *condition1* is falsey or will return *condition2*.

In your expression, its `condition1 && condition2 condition3`. There needs to be an operator between *condition2* and *condition3* or they need correct structure.

---

If you want `label` to always render and icon for `"new"` buttons, it should be:

```
{condition1 && condition2}
{condition3}
```

but if you need them to render together or none, you need to wrap then so that your expression returns 1 value:

```
{
    condition1 &&
    (<>
        element1
        element2
    </>)
}
```

---

**Sample**

```js
const ModalButton1 = ({ label, mode }) => {
  return (
    <button type="submit">
      {
        mode == "new" && (
        <FaPlusCircle style={{ fontSize: "20px", paddingTop: "6px" }} />)
      }
      { label }
    </button>
  );
};


const ModalButton2 = ({ label, mode }) => {
  return (
    <button type="submit">
      {
        mode == "new" && (
          <>
            <FaPlusCircle style={{ fontSize: "20px", paddingTop: "6px" }} />)
            {label}
          </>
      }
    </button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A JSX expression can only return a single value. If you want to return several values, wrap them in an array, like so:

```
{mode == "new" && [<Component/>, label]}
```

Comment: I think you might be being downvoted because "A JSX expression can only return a single element" is slightly misleading, it can only return a single value, but as you have shown, that value can contain multiple elements (in the case of arrays/nested JSX elements) Might be worth clarifying.

Comment: Or possibly having a component with no `key` in an array (but if it were me, I'd just comment that, not downvote).

Comment: @DBS you're right, edited my answer.